# Confusion about notations in limit mixed Hodge structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, mixed-hodge-structure

I am reading the paper Monodromy at infinity and Fourier transform by Claude Sabbah and got some confusions about notations. (note first that I am not specialized in mixed Hodge theory but, I am outsider who is needing some research ideas) Let $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a regular function on a smooth quasi-projective variety $U$. For each $t \in \mathbb{C}$, the cohomology $H^{\bullet}(f^{-1}(t),\mathbb{Q})$ carries a natural mixed Hodge structure; Steenbrink and Zucker constructed a limit mixed Hodge structure when $t \to \infty$. This can be also obtained by considering a compactification of the function $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 = \mathbb{C} \cup \infty$ for which we denote by $F: \mathfrak{X} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, let $\kappa: U \longrightarrow \mathfrak{X}$ be the embedding. At the beginning of section $4$, the author considers a perverse sheaf ${}^p\Psi_{1/F}\mathbf{R}\kappa_*{}^p\mathbb{Q}_U$ where ${}^p\Psi$ is the nearby cycles. I think $1/F$ is only defined over $\mathfrak{X}\setminus \mathfrak{X}_0$ which does not contain $U$, so how can one write something like that?